# How to get gps location of other device in android programatically

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location, android-gps

I'm building a new app. In that app i want to display GPS Location of particular device.

Comment: you can not get a location of another device directly. but you can do it in a different way, like you can request the device for its location and that device can send it to you

Comment: This is how it works:
**Device sends its location to the server  using your app or devices operated via sim cards like trackers attached in vehicles etc** then your app installed in cell phone can receive that information and you can plot it on the map or do whatever you want.
Above are the key words/ways through which you can achieve your goal. Try searching with those. Regards :)

Comment: Hope this helps you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025857/track-other-devices-with-gps-android

and please edit your Question and wrote more discription about what you wants because this is a too broad question:- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask